# What is the difference between a service and an application?

Tags: linux, unix

In UNIX , what is the difference between a service and an application program technically?

Answer (score 2):

- A *service* is a long-running executable that performs specific functions and which is designed not to require user intervention. Services usually provide an interface to start, stop, pause and restart the executable that is running in the background on the computer.
- An *application* runs stand alone in a desktop or laptop computer, by contrast with a web application which requires a web browser to run. Standalone applications in Unix-like operating systems can be further divided into GUI applications and terminal applications.